# Getting this error while upgrading facebook network audience 6.5

Tags: android, flutter, facebook

I'm trying to upgrade Facebook network audience sdk to 6.5 but I'm getting this error.

[image]
 
```

[com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.5.1] /Users/ateeq/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/f9b65d0ff7ac031f789d79123025e640/audience-network-sdk-6.5.1/AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-55 Error:
Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.5.1] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-55
[com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.5.1] /Users/ateeq/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/f9b65d0ff7ac031f789d79123025e640/audience-network-sdk-6.5.1/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Validation failed, exiting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

**Ist u need to go the gradle.properties and put the below code**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.enableAapt2=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**in the  next step go to build.gardle and put the below code**

```
   mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    google()
```

**And your class path**

```
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

**if the ist answer not working please do the following changes only change the classpath**

```
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
```